# How to convert piped/awk output to string/variable

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to create a bash function that automatically updates a cli tool. So far I've managed to get this:

```bash
update_cli_tool () {
    # the following will automatically be redirected to .../releases/tag/vX.X.X
    # there I get the location from the header, and remove it to get the full url
    latest_release_url=$(curl -i https://github.com/.../releases/latest | grep location: | awk -F 'location: ' '{print $2}')
    # to get the version, I get the 8th element from the url .../releases/tag/vX.X.X
    latest_release_version=$(echo "$latest_release_url" | awk -F '/' '{print 8}')
    
    # this is where it breaks
    # the first part just replaces the "tag" with "download" in the url
    full_url="${latest_release_url/tag/download}/.../${latest_release_version}.zip"
    echo "$full_url"  # or curl $full_url, also fails
}
```

Expected output: `https://github.com/.../download/vX.X.X/vX.X.X.zip`

Actual output: `-.zip-.../.../releases/download/vX.X.X`

When I just `echo "latest_release_url: $latest_release_url"` (same for version), it prints it correctly, but not when I use the above mentioned flow. When I hardcode the `..._url` and `..._version`, the `full_url` works fine. So my guess is I have to somehow capture the output and convert it to a string? Or perhaps concatenate it another way?

Note: I've also used `` ..._url=`curl -i ...` ``  (with backticks instead of `$(...)`), but this gave me the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `curl` output will use `\r\n` line endings. The stray carriage return in the url variable is tripping you up. Observe it with `printf '%q\n' "$latest_release_url"`

Try this:

```bash
latest_release_url=$(
    curl --silent -i https://github.com/.../releases/latest \
    | awk -v RS='\r\n' '$1 == "location:" {print $2}'
)
```

Then the rest of the script should look right.

Comment: Amazing, that's exactly what I was trying to achieve. It works flawlessly now. Thanks! P.S. the `--silent` is also a nice addition.